# Problem running Gremlin query in CosmosDb

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a problem running this Gremlin query in Azure CosmosDB.

```
g.V().
  has('node', 'id', 'new').
  fold().coalesce(
    unfold(),
    addV('node').
    property('id', 'new').
    property('partitionKey', 'edd1f6ca3b1c446987d7da29e370cc7e')
  ).V().
  has('node', 'id', 'new').
    as('new').
  V().
  has('node', 'id', 'root').
  coalesce(
    outE('contains').where(inV().as('new')),
    addE('contains').to('new')
  ).V().
  has('node', 'id', 'new').
    as('new').
  V().has('userGroup', 'id', 'userGroup1').
  coalesce(
    outE('hasAccess').where(inV().as('new')),
    addE('hasAccess').to('new')
  )
```

I get two problems:

1. If I have many other nodes in the DB (350000) the query times out. I have not been able to test this in TinkerPop.
2. The hasAccess edge is not created. This works in TinkerPop.

The base for the query is (images from [gremlify.com](https://gremlify.com)):

[image]

```
g.addV('node').
  property('id', 'root').
  property('partitionKey', '33cb2571f8e348eaa875e6a2639af385')
```

```
g.addV('userGroup').
  property('id', 'userGroup1').
  property('partitionKey', '1')
```

and I want to end up like:

[image]

with a query that can be run multiple times without changing anything (idempotent). If I do this in separate queries it works fine:

```
g.V().
  has('node', 'id', 'new').
  fold().coalesce(
    unfold(),
    addV('node').
    property('id', 'new').
    property('partitionKey', 'edd1f6ca3b1c446987d7da29e370cc7e')
  )
```

```
g.V().
  has('node', 'id', 'new').
    as('new').
  V().
  has('node', 'id', 'root').
  coalesce(
    outE('contains').where(inV().as('new')),
    addE('contains').to('new')
  )
```

```
g.V().
  has('node', 'id', 'new').
    as('new').
  V().has('userGroup', 'id', 'userGroup1').
  coalesce(
    outE('hasAccess').where(inV().as('new')),
    addE('hasAccess').to('new')
  )
```

But I want to save two calls to the DB and do it in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience using the `V()` step in the middle of a traversal is not well optimized in some vendors, even when followed by a strong filter like `has('id', <name>)`, and I think you should try to avoid using it if you want to do a single query.
you can try:

```
g.V().hasLabel('node', 'userGroup').has('_id', within('new', 'root', 'userGroup1')).
  fold().as('vertices').coalesce(
    unfold().has('node', '_id', 'new'),
    addV('node').property('_id', 'new').
    property('partitionKey', 'edd1f6ca3b1c446987d7da29e370cc7e')
  ).as('new').
  select('vertices').unfold().has('node', '_id', 'root').coalesce(
    outE('contains').where(inV().as('new')),
    addE('contains').to('new')
  ).
  select('vertices').unfold().has('userGroup', '_id', 'userGroup1')
  coalesce(
    outE('hasAccess').where(inV().as('new')),
    addE('hasAccess').to('new')
  )
```

example: https://gremlify.com/pdtla2bsrc/1